# downloaded image of the Signature from the canvas disappears after blinking in a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to capture the signature of the user through signaturepad and canvas and downloading the same into device in a project in phonegap cordova. The image is getting downloaded but it is disappearing the very next minute.

Dont know where is the issue in my code. I have attached my code snippet also.

Link for the file transfer plugin- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

```js
//register.js
var imageURI;
var imageURIsign;
var signaturePad;
var canvas;

$(document).ready(function() {



  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

});


function onDeviceReady() {


}






function callcanvas() {

  //$('#test').popup('open');
  $('#test').attr("style", "display:block");
  alert("Inside call canvas...");
  canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  // As the canvas doesn't has any size, we'll specify it with JS
  // The width of the canvas will be the width of the device
  canvas.width = w;
  // The height of the canvas will be (almost) the third part of the screen height.
  canvas.height = h / 2.5;

  signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
    dotSize: 1
  });

  document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Feel free to do whatever you want with the image
    // as export to a server or even save it on the device.
    //imageURIsign=signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    imageURIsign = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("preview").src = imageURIsign;
    alert("imageURIsign :-" + imageURIsign);

    //downloadFile();

  }, false);

  document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Clears the canvas
    signaturePad.clear();
  }, false);
}


/*$(".img-download").click(function(){
    var data = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    $(this).attr("href",data)
  $(this).attr("download","imgName.png");
});*/

//yyy add
function downloadFile() {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var downloadurl = document.getElementById("preview").src;
  var uri = encodeURI(downloadurl);


  var fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/test.jpg';

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("error :- " + JSON.stringify(error));
      <!--alert("download error source " + error.source);-->
      <!--alert("download error target " + error.target);-->
      <!--alert("download error code" + error.code);-->
    },

    false, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
      }
    }
  );
}




function DownloadFile(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //Parameters mismatch check
  if (URL == null && Folder_Name == null && File_Name == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    //checking Internet connection availablity
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
      return;
    } else {
      download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name); //If available download function call
    }
  }
}


function download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //step to request a file system
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

  function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
    ext = download_link.substr(download_link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //Get extension of URL

    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, {
      create: true,
      exclusive: false
    }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
    var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
    var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fulpath of local directory
    console.log("harsh_link:- " + fp);

    fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name + "." + ext; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
    // download function call
    filetransfer(download_link, fp);
  }

  function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    // Directory created successfuly
  }

  function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    //Error while creating directory
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
  }

  function fileSystemFail(evt) {
    //Unable to access file system
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
  }
}



function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  // File download function with URL and local path
  fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
      //Download abort errors or download failed errors
      alert("download error source " + error.source);
      //alert("download error target " + error.target);
      //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
  );
}

//yyy add
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

  <title>Register User</title>

</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="callcanvas()">Signature</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="downloadFile()">DownloadSignature</button><br><br>

  <div id="test" style="display:none;">

    <canvas id="signature" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <img id="preview" />
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">

      <input type="button" id="export" value="Export" />
      <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>

  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is `FileTransfer ` a plugin? if so link it please, since its pretty relevant for the code to work

Comment: yes It is a plugin,I have added that plugin and it is already working and also allowing me to download the image but when I try to open the downloaded image, it just blinks and disappears leaving a black screen.@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I understand the problem you have, but without the plugin its hard for us to test the problem and help you with a solution, Please Update your snippet so it reflects an example of your problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have added the link for the plugin. can you please help me out with that now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the background colour as opaque white, as signature pad was taking black by default , my issue is solved by changing the background colour.

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas,{

backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",

```
dotSize: 1
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
//register.js
var imageURI;
var imageURIsign;
var signaturePad;
var canvas;

$(document).ready(function() {



  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

});


function onDeviceReady() {


}






function callcanvas() {

  //$('#test').popup('open');
  $('#test').attr("style", "display:block");
  alert("Inside call canvas...");
  canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  // As the canvas doesn't has any size, we'll specify it with JS
  // The width of the canvas will be the width of the device
  canvas.width = w;
  // The height of the canvas will be (almost) the third part of the screen height.
  canvas.height = h / 2.5;

  signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
    dotSize: 1
  });

  document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Feel free to do whatever you want with the image
    // as export to a server or even save it on the device.
    //imageURIsign=signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    imageURIsign = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("preview").src = imageURIsign;
    alert("imageURIsign :-" + imageURIsign);

    //downloadFile();

  }, false);

  document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Clears the canvas
    signaturePad.clear();
  }, false);
}


/*$(".img-download").click(function(){
    var data = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    $(this).attr("href",data)
  $(this).attr("download","imgName.png");
});*/

//yyy add
function downloadFile() {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var downloadurl = document.getElementById("preview").src;
  var uri = encodeURI(downloadurl);


  var fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/test.jpg';

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("error :- " + JSON.stringify(error));
      <!--alert("download error source " + error.source);-->
      <!--alert("download error target " + error.target);-->
      <!--alert("download error code" + error.code);-->
    },

    false, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
      }
    }
  );
}




function DownloadFile(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //Parameters mismatch check
  if (URL == null && Folder_Name == null && File_Name == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    //checking Internet connection availablity
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
      return;
    } else {
      download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name); //If available download function call
    }
  }
}


function download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //step to request a file system
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

  function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
    ext = download_link.substr(download_link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //Get extension of URL

    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, {
      create: true,
      exclusive: false
    }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
    var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
    var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fulpath of local directory
    console.log("harsh_link:- " + fp);

    fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name + "." + ext; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
    // download function call
    filetransfer(download_link, fp);
  }

  function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    // Directory created successfuly
  }

  function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    //Error while creating directory
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
  }

  function fileSystemFail(evt) {
    //Unable to access file system
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
  }
}



function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  // File download function with URL and local path
  fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
      //Download abort errors or download failed errors
      alert("download error source " + error.source);
      //alert("download error target " + error.target);
      //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
  );
}

//yyy add
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

  <title>Register User</title>

</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="callcanvas()">Signature</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="downloadFile()">DownloadSignature</button><br><br>

  <div id="test" style="display:none;">

    <canvas id="signature" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <img id="preview" />
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">

      <input type="button" id="export" value="Export" />
      <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>

  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
//register.js
var imageURI;
var imageURIsign;
var signaturePad;
var canvas;

$(document).ready(function() {



  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

});


function onDeviceReady() {


}






function callcanvas() {

  //$('#test').popup('open');
  $('#test').attr("style", "display:block");
  alert("Inside call canvas...");
  canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  // As the canvas doesn't has any size, we'll specify it with JS
  // The width of the canvas will be the width of the device
  canvas.width = w;
  // The height of the canvas will be (almost) the third part of the screen height.
  canvas.height = h / 2.5;

  signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
    dotSize: 1
  });

  document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Feel free to do whatever you want with the image
    // as export to a server or even save it on the device.
    //imageURIsign=signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    imageURIsign = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("preview").src = imageURIsign;
    alert("imageURIsign :-" + imageURIsign);

    //downloadFile();

  }, false);

  document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Clears the canvas
    signaturePad.clear();
  }, false);
}


/*$(".img-download").click(function(){
    var data = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    $(this).attr("href",data)
  $(this).attr("download","imgName.png");
});*/

//yyy add
function downloadFile() {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var downloadurl = document.getElementById("preview").src;
  var uri = encodeURI(downloadurl);


  var fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/test.jpg';

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("error :- " + JSON.stringify(error));
      <!--alert("download error source " + error.source);-->
      <!--alert("download error target " + error.target);-->
      <!--alert("download error code" + error.code);-->
    },

    false, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
      }
    }
  );
}




function DownloadFile(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //Parameters mismatch check
  if (URL == null && Folder_Name == null && File_Name == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    //checking Internet connection availablity
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
      return;
    } else {
      download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name); //If available download function call
    }
  }
}


function download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
  //step to request a file system
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

  function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
    ext = download_link.substr(download_link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //Get extension of URL

    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, {
      create: true,
      exclusive: false
    }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
    var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
    var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fulpath of local directory
    console.log("harsh_link:- " + fp);

    fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name + "." + ext; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
    // download function call
    filetransfer(download_link, fp);
  }

  function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    // Directory created successfuly
  }

  function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    //Error while creating directory
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
  }

  function fileSystemFail(evt) {
    //Unable to access file system
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
  }
}



function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  // File download function with URL and local path
  fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
    function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
      //Download abort errors or download failed errors
      alert("download error source " + error.source);
      //alert("download error target " + error.target);
      //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
  );
}

//yyy add
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

  <title>Register User</title>

</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="callcanvas()">Signature</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="downloadFile()">DownloadSignature</button><br><br>

  <div id="test" style="display:none;">

    <canvas id="signature" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <img id="preview" />
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">

      <input type="button" id="export" value="Export" />
      <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>

  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please paste something except of code. Explain main idea that was used or what should be explored to avoid such question in the future. And since You mostly(?) copypasted original question, it would be nice to add explanation what have been changed